# Получение значение между скобками в javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток, в регулярках javascript я не очень силен, поэтому прошу помощи.

Преположим есть текст такого вида:

```
var text = "Пример текста с «такими скобками»";
```

Так вот, суть задачи заключается в том, что мне нужно отдельно получить

> Пример текст с

и отдельно

> «такими скобками»

Заранее спасибо

Comment: и где пример вашей регулярки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var text = "Пример текста с «такими скобками»";
console.log(text.split(/(«.*»)/));
```

Comment: `"Пример текста с«такими скобками» и еще что-нибудь тут«такими скобками»"` - на таком не сработает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос тольков том, каким должно быть поведение в подобном случае в принципе.

Comment: @Darth огонь, спасибо :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `/(«.*?»)/`

Comment: @Darth более похоже на правду.... но ТС, видимо, плевать)

Comment: @k0mar обратите внимание на мой комментарий и комментарий ниже